# How to perform a merge operation on dataset/dataframe in sparksql - Python

Tags: merge, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In SQL, you can perform `MERGE` operation on a table and insert/update data into it. Example: [merge in snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/merge.html)

Are we able to do something similar in pyspark.sql?

Comment: if you have databricks you can append to delta lake table.. otherwise you can just overwrite s3

Comment: I don't think append/overwrite is what I'm after. I need to conditionally update some columns if the key is existing otherwise do an insert.

Comment: are u using databricks for pyspark?

Comment: No databricks for now, but can be considered if it indeed solves my problem.

Comment: i think this link might make a case for u: https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html . im pretty sure you can also use open source delta lake for similar things, it just wont have databricks optimizations

Comment: https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html#conditional-update-without-overwrite - open source

Comment: Thank you, @MohammadMurtazaHashmi. Will read and test out.